# cgroup and process memory usage mismactch

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, cgroups, procfs

I have a memory cgroup with 1 process in it.
And look for rss memory usage in that cgroup (in memory.stat) and it is much bigger than rss memory of the process (from `/proc/[pid]/status`).

The only process pid in cgroup:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/karim/master/cgroup.procs
3744924
```

The memory limit in cgroup:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/karim/master/memory.limit_in_bytes
7340032000
```

rss of the cgroup is 990 MB:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/karim/master/memory.stat
cache 5990449152
rss 990224384
rss_huge 0
shmem 0
mapped_file 13516800
dirty 1081344
writeback 270336
pgpgin 4195191
pgpgout 2490628
pgfault 5264589
pgmajfault 0
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 990240768
inactive_file 5862830080
active_file 127021056
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 7340032000
total_cache 5990449152
total_rss 990224384
total_rss_huge 0
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 13516800
total_dirty 1081344
total_writeback 270336
total_pgpgin 4195191
total_pgpgout 2490628
total_pgfault 5264589
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 990240768
total_inactive_file 5862830080
total_active_file 127021056
total_unevictable 0
```

rss of the process is 165 MB:

```
$ cat /proc/3744924/status
Name:   [main]       /h
Umask:  0002
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   3744924
Ngid:   0
Pid:    3744924
PPid:   3744912
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1001    1001    1001    1001
FDSize: 256
Groups: 1000 1001
NStgid: 3744924
NSpid:  3744924
NSpgid: 3744912
NSsid:  45028
VmPeak:  2149068 kB
VmSize:  2088876 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    245352 kB
VmRSS:    198964 kB
RssAnon:      165248 kB
RssFile:       33660 kB
RssShmem:         56 kB
VmData:   575400 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:      3048 kB
VmLib:     19180 kB
VmPTE:      1152 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
CoreDumping:    0
THP_enabled:    1
Threads:    17
SigQ:   0/241014
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001001000
SigCgt: 0000000180000002
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
NoNewPrivs: 0
Seccomp:    0
Speculation_Store_Bypass:   thread vulnerable
Cpus_allowed:   fff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-11
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    94902
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 1903
```

Why is there such a big difference?

Comment: @Karim Can you include the memory limit of the cgroup and include the other memory statistics from `memory.stat` and `/proc/pid/status`? Interested in seeing if the math adds up with other memory categories.

Comment: @wxz i've updated the question with memory limit and full outputs